# ASP.NET how to persist user uploaded files across each deploy

Tags: asp.net, appharbor

I am new to asp.net. I have created an web application and hosted in appharbor.com. I created a folder below the project to store the user uploaded files(\photo\product). However this folder is not persist across each deploy. Is there any common approach to solve this problem? Any guide will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using WebDeploy to deploy the application to AppHarbor.  You can instruct WebDeploy to not delete existing files on the server from MSBuild using the following MSBuild argument:

```
/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=true
```

OR during the MSDeploy deployment using the following argument:

```
-enableRule:DoNotDelete
```